# Apply a dynamic style to a raster(GeoServer, OpenLayers)

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wcs

I want to apply a dynamic style to a raster using either GeoServer or OpenLayers.
I have found similar examples at [OpenLayers plugins](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.colorize.html) but these examples work on RGB images instead of the real values of the raster.

An example of a similar tool that I want to develop:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Have a look at this example for ideas of how it can be done on the client side: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/raster.html

Comment: You could set a SLD parameter in the OpenLayers WMS source `params` option and update using `updateParams()`